# Encountering problem while posting and fetching data using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My ajax code:

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {
        var usercheck = $(this).val();
                $('#nameAvailability').html('<img src="../SPR/assets/img/loading.gif" width="300" />'); //this part is working
                $.post("../SPR/backend/username_availability_check.php", {user_name: usercheck} ,  
                function(data)
                {
                if (data.status == true)
                {
                $('#nameAvailability').parent('div').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
                
                } else {
                $('#nameAvailability').parent('div').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                }
                $('#nameAvailability').html(data.msg); // not working
                } ,'json');

        });
```

My php code:

```
<?php
require("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['user_name']) && $_POST['user_name'] != '')
    {
        $response = array();
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['user_name']);
        echo $username;
        $sql  = "select username from users where users.username='".$username."'";
        $res    = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $count  = mysqli_num_rows($res);
        if($count > 0)
        {
            $response['status'] = false;
            $response['msg'] = 'Username already exists.';
        }
        else if(strlen($username) < 6 || strlen($username) > 15){
            $response['status'] = false;
            $response['msg'] = 'Username must be 6 to 15 characters';
        }
        else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z1-9]+$/", $username))
        {
            $response['status'] = false;
            $response['msg'] = 'Use alphanumeric characters only.';
        }
        else
        {
            $response['status'] = true;
            $response['msg'] = 'Username is available.';
        }
         echo json_encode($response);
         echo $response;
    }
?>
```

I have used session_start() in my index.php where user inputs his username in the input field with id 'name' 
I have checked the given php code by running it individually by passing a custom username from the database and it works fine. So probably there's something wrong with the ajax code.

Comment: You should describe in more detail the problem you're encountering. Is the `$.post` callback being invoked at all? Is `data.status` not matching what you would expect?

Comment: What's the response that you're getting in  `data.msg`

Comment: @AmitSharma NO RESPONSE. That's the problem

Comment: Is the request being made in the first place? Have you checked the networks tab? What does it say?

Comment: @JaredASutton Yes it's showing up on the network but no result on the page

Comment: @AmitSharma Yes, it's showing up on the networks tab and is getting invoked everytime keyup event is fired

Comment: And what's the response?

Comment: @AmitSharma No response

Comment: That's weird. If an attempt to connect to a server is made by the browser, at least some status is reflected back, even if the server is non-responsive.

Comment: Are you trying to test this locally? Is your server hosted on localhost?

Comment: Remove all the echo except echo json_encode($response);
if(isset($_POST['user_name']) && $_POST['user_name'] != '') for this add else part make it as return false with error message  as json_encode

Comment: @AmitSharma Yes it's hosted locally

Comment: Please edit the post to write the error you get.

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to tell what your clientside code does based on what is posted here.

But in general, for debugging and to check if your serverside code works, do this:

Make a simple form, that POSTS to your PHP script.

```
<form action="whateveryourphpcodeisnamed.php" METHOD="POST">
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="user_name">
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="TEST THE USERNAME">
</FORM>
```

And see what it says back to you.

Be sure to activate error_reporting during development.